# Angular Material Date Range Picker setting Values coming from API

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've a sceranrio where getting the data in below format and tried to utilize [date range picker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples#date-range-picker-comparison) but it's required to create the FormGroup in .ts. Not sure how to achieve this as this need to display on page in grid layout.

```
[
{beginDate: Mon Jun 26 2023, endDate: Tue Jun 27 2023, name: 'test1'}, 
{beginDate: Thu Jun 29 2023, endDate: Fri Jun 30 2023, name: 'test2'}, 
{beginDate: Fri Jul 07 2023, endDate: Sat Jul 08 2023, name: 'test3'}
]
```

I've grab all the information on HTML but it's not accepting input in comparisonStart and comparisonEnd as this will only accept the data from FormGroup
<mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="range" [rangePicker]="picker" [comparisonStart]="" [comparisonEnd]="">

As the data is dynamic so I can't create hard coded FormGroup in .ts file to map over this.